# How to delete unix files from a directory with common name except the latest one

Tags: file, unix, delete-file

I have multiple files in the name format as mentioned below:

1. ABC_Report_v-20120801_1741.csv
2. ABC_Report_v-20120801_1741.csv
3. ABC_Report_v-20120907_1254.csv
4. XYZ_Dashboard_v-20120802_1804.csv
5. XYZ_Dashboard_v-20120806_2031.csv
6. XYZ_Dashboard_v-20120802_1946.csv

I want to delete all the files except the latest one like `ABC_Report_v-20120907_1254.csv` and `XYZ_Dashboard_v-20120802_1946.csv`
The multiple files with the same name before `_v` characters should be removed keeping the latest one only.

Comment: you can delete multiple files using wildcards in the commands like "rm ABC_Report_v-*.csv". You can figure out something like this

Comment: This was just an example of two files in the directory, there are many more files with the name in the given format. To delete manually one by one of same name format is not possible and moreover I have to keep the latest one and remove the rest files.

Comment: `ls -1t ABC_Report_*.csv|awk '{if(NR!=1){cmd="rm -rf "$0;system(cmd);}}'`

Comment: Thanx Sarathi for the command, but how do I generalize the first part of the command ls -1t ABC_Report_*.csv for other file names. In this case we have to give each file name individually as in the 2nd case it will be XYZ_Dashboard_*.csv . I want to generalize this part of the command for other files having the name in this format only.

Comment: How do you want to generalize the description of a group?  Everything that shares a name up to the first dash?  The first underscore?

Comment: Yes Ghoti, everything that shares a name up to the first dash

Comment: 1. Extract the name of the one you want preserved, based on whatever criteria you want (find and ls should have that covered).  2. Move it elsewhere, just make sure you got space, inodes, permissions, and it does not collide with an existing file (moving it within the same partition makes it also really fast!).  3. Delete everything from the directory you want clean.  4. Move the preserved file back.

Comment: @Marcin - sounds like your suggestion could be implemented programmatically. Why not make it an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Note that this does not protect against duplicate lines.  You should `uniq` your file list before processing it like this, or remember to ignore the errors when you try to remove files that are already gone.

```
$ awk -F- 'NR>1 && $1==base {print last} {base=$1;last=$0}' files.txt
ABC_Report_v-20120801_1741.csv
ABC_Report_v-20120801_1741.csv
XYZ_Dashboard_v-20120802_1804.csv
XYZ_Dashboard_v-20120806_2031.csv
```

From here, once you've verified that the files matched are the ones to keep, you can pipe the output through `xargs -n 1 rm`.

Note that this solution *requires* that your file list be pre-sorted by date.  This should be the default behaviour of `ls` on most systems.  So:

```
$ ls | awk '...' | xargs -n 1 rm -v
```

Always back up your data before doing programmatic removals where you're not 100% confident in what you're doing.  Heck, always back up your data anyway.  Never know when the next sun spot will hit.

Comment: Thanx Ghoti, the above command $ ls | awk '...' | xargs -n 1 rm -v worked perfectly.

Comment: what should be change in the above command if I want to keep the latest 2 files and remove the rest all

Comment: Well, you'll need to keep two sets of `last` and `base` variables instead of just one.  Think about how this works.  You're keeping a running "window" of the previous line, and printing it when the line changes.  Can you adapt it yourself?  Why not try, then post another question if you hit a wall?